# How do I call a method to automatically send an email in the controller?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, email, smtpclient

I need to be able to send automatic emails to any users who have registered new accounts, changed passwords, and/or created new orders.

I've been given the SendEmail file, which belongs in the "Utilities" folder in my solution.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

namespace SendEmail

{
public static class EmailMessaging
{
    public static void SendEmail(String toEmailAddress, String emailSubject, String emailBody)
    {
      
        //Create a variable for YOUR TEAM'S Email address
        //This is the address that will be SENDING the emails (the FROM address)
        String strFromEmailAddress = "email@gmail.com";

        //This is the password for YOUR TEAM'S "fake" Gmail account
        String strPassword = "Password";

        //This is the name of the business from which you are sending
        //TODO: Change this to the name of the company you are creating the website for
        String strCompanyName = "Team Final Project";

        //Create an email client to send the emails
        //port 587 is required to work, do not change it
        var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            //This is the SENDING email address and password
            //This will be your team's email address and password
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strFromEmailAddress, strPassword),
            EnableSsl = true
        };


        //Add anything that you need to the body of the message
        //emailBody is passed into the method as a parameter
        // /n is a new line – this will add some white space after the main body of the message
        //TODO: Change or remove the disclaimer below
        String finalMessage = emailBody + "\n\n Thank you, come back again soon!";

        //Create an email address object for the sender address
        MailAddress senderEmail = new MailAddress(strFromEmailAddress, strCompanyName);

        //Create a new mail message
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();

        //Set the subject line of the message (including your team number)
        mm.Subject = "Team ## - " + "Thank you!";

        //Set the sender address
        mm.Sender = senderEmail;

        //Set the from address
        mm.From = senderEmail;

        //Add the recipient (passed in as a parameter) to the list of people receiving the email
        mm.To.Add(new MailAddress(toEmailAddress));

        //Add the message (passed)
        mm.Body = finalMessage;

        //send the message!
        client.Send(mm);
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that neither I nor my team members know how to implement call this from the controller in a way that will be sent automatically and with the user's email and name. We imagine they will be in the Account and Orders controllers. The accounts controller has the register and change password methods, which work, and the orders controller has the complete order method.

Also, we are **not** using a confirmation view, it has to be an automatic email.

We need some direction in figuring out where exactly we need to call the method from and how.

The most helpful thing I've found on the internet today is this block of code for a test message that is not intended to be sending automatic emails.

```
public static void CreateTestMessage(string server)
        {
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("sender@gmail.com", "Team Project");
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("reciever@gmail.com", "Customer");
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        message.Subject = "Password Changed";
        message.Body = @"This is a confirmation email that your password has been changed.";
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        
        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateBccTestMessage(): {0}",
                ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Everything is being coded on MS VS

Answer (score 0):

First create a service for EmailService and put SendEmailAsync Method in it
and call this method on your Controller.

In Method body:
1-Create your message:

```
var mm = new MailMessage()
```

2-Then you should build your smtp:

```
using  var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
```

3-Then connect it to your server

```
await smtpClient.ConnectAsync(
                "your host",
                "port",
                SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
```

4-Now send your Email:

```
await smtpClient.SendAsync(mm);
```

5-Make sure that disconnect from your client:

```
await smtpClient.DisconnectAsync(true);
```

**Note**: It may give you an Exception while Connecting or Sending your Email so don't forget try catch block.

6-For Automation you can use a **EmailAccount** Table with relation with your **Customer** Table and keep your message data in it.
for ex: body ,subject..... .

In your Contorller you have your Customer So you can get his **EmailAccount** from **DataBase** and pass **EmailAccount** Entity to **SendEmailAsync** Method.

instead of creating message in body, get it from **EmailAccount** Entity and then countinue the Steps.

7-Enjoy it :)